# Error when importing tf2onnx through Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, onnx

I have a new env in conda and if I run the following command after activating the env, it will be successful:

```
python -c "import tf2onnx"
```

But, if I run the same command (after activating the env) with Jupyter notebook, I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-9d842ab860c9> in <module>
----> 1 import tf2onnx

C:\Miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras2onnx\ktf2onnx\tf2onnx\__init__.py in <module>
     11 from .version import version as __version__
     12 from . import logging
---> 13 from tf2onnx import tfonnx, utils, graph, graph_matcher, shape_inference, schemas  # pylint: disable=wrong-import-order

C:\Miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras2onnx\ktf2onnx\tf2onnx\tfonnx.py in <module>
     23 import tf2onnx.onnx_opset  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     24 import tf2onnx.custom_opsets  # pylint: disable=unused-import
---> 25 from tf2onnx.graph import Graph
     26 from tf2onnx.graph_matcher import OpTypePattern, GraphMatcher
     27 from tf2onnx.rewriter import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import

C:\Miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras2onnx\ktf2onnx\tf2onnx\graph.py in <module>
     19 
     20 from distutils.version import StrictVersion
---> 21 from onnx import helper, numpy_helper, shape_inference, OperatorSetIdProto, AttributeProto, version
     22 from tf2onnx import utils, __version__
     23 from tf2onnx.utils import port_name, find_opset

ImportError: cannot import name 'shape_inference'
```

What is the difference between running this command with or without jupyter that causes this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have multiple conda environments, this can usually lead to having multiple kernels within Jupyter. Can you double check to make sure you're using the same environment in both places?

Comment: I checked and I only have one conda env.

Comment: Try updating to the latest versions of everything if you're not there already. It is working fine for me with tf2onnx 1.5.1, tensorflow 1.13.1, and python 3.7.3.

Comment: I tried several scenarios, one includes 'conda clean -all' and then delete all envs and create a new one with everything fresh and updated. But still getting the same error!

Comment: Can you tell me what version of `onnx` you have by running `pip show onnx` within the environment?I have the latest version which is 1.5.0.

Comment: I also have the latest version: 1.5.0

Comment: I apologize, but I cannot recreate your issue. Unfortunately, it looks like a common solution to uninstall/reinstall anaconda to fix issues. Maybe give that a go?